# Is it possible to use 2 different datsets in a single Rowgrouping in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-grouping

I am using SSRS 2012 for the reports design.

I have 2 different datasets which has the location details from different sql server DBs.

I want to group the location from each dataset and display the value for each location.

Is there any possibility we can use 2 datasets in a single row grouping?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: A Tablix (Table/Matrix) can only reference a single dataset directly. If you need data from another dataset then you need to use the LOOKUP function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @AlanSchofield : yes, we can use lookup function in the tablix data display. but my question is if we can use it in rowgrouping expression.

Comment: I've not tried it personally, I always combine the data in the dataset query if possible but as far as I know, and assuming that you are only getting a single value back from the `LOOKUP()` (location name for example) then you should be able to use that in your rowgroup and sorting expressions. Just give it a try I guess.